# making a database in mysql without duplicate values

Tags: mysql, database

I have a tab separated text file in the format

```
id | field 1 | field 2 ...
```

I want to insert this into a mysql database with id as the primary key but the text file may contain duplicate id's .

1. How to make sure that there's just one entry corresponding to each id.
2. How to make a choice between two lines having the same id (Yes, they might not be consistent, but it's okay to choose one over other like the first or the last occurrence )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a `SELECT` before `INSERT` and count the number of rows returned by the `SELECT`. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE yourTable.id = :id
```

If that returns any row, don't insert and go to next.  Otherwise insert it.

Edit: This would be a post strategy.  It would be good if you could add a [Unique Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) to guarantee uniqueness.  Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD CONSTRAINT ukID UNIQUE (id)
```

Comment: it's not in any table yet, it's in a text file. You mean I should first make a database and then another one out of it?

Comment: Create a table that fits your needs (don't forget to add the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for that id field).  Then you can do either what I suggested or what @AVD suggested in order to add your file rows into the database.  What AVD suggested is more efficient since you will need just one query to insert into the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Read line by line from text file, parse that line and use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` [Syntax.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming a Unix shell, I'd do this:

```
awk '!x[$1]++' inputfile.tsv > uniqfile.tsv
```

then do your import off of the uniqfile.

*edit*: to be clear, that script uniq's the input file based on the first field by only outputting rows that do not already have a non-zero value in a hash keyed off of the first field.